# Need to write ifError function into R

Tags: r, excel

I need to apply an IFERROR formula for as below for the above calculation.

it has number of days and sales generated on that particular day and then the result for the respectives days.

```
days        cost        result

2022-01-02   1326        0
2022-01-03   1326        0
2022-01-04   1326        0
2022-01-05   1326        0
2022-01-06   1326        -1
```

here we get the score by applying the below formula.

```
=IFERROR((B2-B1)/B1,0)
```

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: `with(dat, c(NA, diff(cost))/cost)` is one start, not sure what the "error" part of your need for `IFERROR` is.

Comment: I have a thought ... I think Excel's `IFERROR(.., 0)` is very much like SQL's (and `dplyr` and `data.table`) "COALESCE". Since differencing will inherently produce one shorter length than the original vector/column, my comment above introduces an `NA` to retain the length. One could easily do `c(0, diff(cost))/cost` for an in-place literal replacement, but if you suspect you'll have `NA` or `NaN` values due to the values, then `dplyr::coalesce(c(NA, diff(cost))/cost, 0)` would cover those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I've misunderstood the question, but one potential option is to use the `is.na()` function, and the `lead()` function from the [dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr-package.html), e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- read.table(text = "days        cost        result

2022-01-02   1326        0
2022-01-03   1326        0
2022-01-04   1326        0
2022-01-05   1326        0
2022-01-06   1326        -1",
header = TRUE)

df$score <- ifelse(is.na((lead(df$cost, default = 0) - df$cost)/df$cost),
                   0, (lead(df$cost, default = 0) - df$cost)/df$cost)
df
#>         days cost result score
#> 1 2022-01-02 1326      0     0
#> 2 2022-01-03 1326      0     0
#> 3 2022-01-04 1326      0     0
#> 4 2022-01-05 1326      0     0
#> 5 2022-01-06 1326     -1    -1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>